# why the distance factor (r) in Newton's law of gravitation is taken to be the distance between COM of two bodies?

Tags: forces

Why 'r' in gravitational force of attraction between two bodies i.e. F = GmM/r^2 , is consideted to be the distance between COM of the two bodies ? Why it is not considered to be the distance between their COG ?

Comment: Neither is correct, where did you hear this?

Comment: What do you mean by center of gravity? The two terms are often used interchangeably.

Comment: Are you just considering spherical objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the $r$ in the gravitational force formula is *not* the distance between the centers of mass, or the distance between the centers of gravity.

However, for two *spherically symmetric* mass distributions (good approximations for, say, Earth and Sun), the $r$ is the distance between their centers (which in this case happen to be the centers of mass). The reason is the [shell theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem). Proving it was one of Newton’s motivations for inventing calculus!

Otherwise, if the distributions aren’t spherically symmetric, then in general you have to integrate the attractions between each pair of infinitesimal masses in each object, treating these like point masses. You can think about it as every atom in one mass distribution attracts every atom in the other mass distribution.

Of course, within a *single* mass distribution every atom also attracts every atom. But these forces cancel and give no net force, which makes for an uninteresting calculation.

Answer (score 1):

There are relevant answers to your  [previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/527805/why-com-and-cog-are-different-things)  .

The center of mass of a solid body is the same in all [inertial frames.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_frame_of_reference) The *center of gravity depends on the gravitational field existing in a given inertial frame*. In physics one uses invariant quantities to transformations between inertial frames.

Mathematically assuming that all the mass is at the center of mass is a first order approximation  to the body, higher order mass density distribution   enters when accuracy is required in  gravitational field calculation.