# Star with quadrupole in binary system violates Newton's 3th law?

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity, stars, multipole-expansion, binary-stars

Suppose that, in a binary system of two stars, the star A (and only the star A) has a non-zero quadrupole moment $Q_A$. Then, the  star B feels the usual gravity force   plus an additional force, since the potential star B feels is:

\begin{equation}
\Phi_B = - \dfrac{GM_A}{r} - \dfrac{3 G Q_A}{2 r^3} .
\end{equation}

On the other hand,  star A  feels only the usual gravity force, since $Q_{B}=0$ for hypothesis, and hence the second term above is not present for star A:

\begin{equation}
\Phi_A = - \dfrac{GM_B}{r} .
\end{equation}

However, applying Newton's third law, one would expect that the forces  on the two stars are equals (in modulo), but this is not the case, since force on B has an additional term. When $Q_A=0$ everything is ok and Newton's 3th law works.  How is it possible?

---

**EDIT:**
Based on the answer below, the force experienced by star A is:

\begin{equation}\tag{1}
F_A = -M_A \partial_r \Phi_A - \dfrac{1}{6}\partial_r \partial_i\partial_j \Phi_A  Q_{A}^{ij}
\end{equation}

where $\Phi_A$ is the potential experienced by star A in its CM. On the other hand, the force acting on star B is:

\begin{equation}\tag{2}
F_B = -M_B \partial_r \Phi_B 
\end{equation}

where I used $Q_B=0$ by hypothesis. Using definitions of $\Phi_{A,B}$ above, I find

\begin{equation}
F_A = - \dfrac{GM_A M_B}{r^2} - \dfrac{GM_B Q_A}{r^4}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
F_B = - \dfrac{GM_A M_B}{r^2} - \dfrac{9}{2}\dfrac{GM_B Q_A}{r^4}
\end{equation}

which depend both on $Q_A$ but are still not equal. I suspect an error in the calculation of the term $\partial_i \partial_j \partial_k \Phi_A Q^{ij}$ [ *the only important component of $Q$ is that along the line connecting the stars, i.e. $Q=Q^{rr}$ in polar coordinates. So, in Eq. (1) I just did   $\partial_r \partial_r \partial_r \Phi_A Q^{rr} = \dfrac{6GM_B}{r^4} Q^{rr}$* ].

Why there is a discrepancy by a factor 9/2?

Answer (score 4):

While the *potential* $\Phi_A$ seen by star $A$ is as you've given above, the *force* it experiences is not simply $-M_A \nabla \Phi_A$.  Only if an object is spherically symmetric will the gravitational force on it be equal to the force on a point mass at the same position as the object's CM.  In general, the force on an extended object will depend not just on its mass $M$ but also on its higher-order multipole moments.

To show this mathematically, let's consider an extended object with a mass density $\rho(\mathbf{r})$ in some external potential $\Phi(\mathbf{r})$ satisfying $\nabla^2 \Phi = 0$.  Choose the origin of our coordinate system to be the center of mass of the object.  The net force on this object is
$$
F_i = -\iiint \rho(\mathbf{r}) \partial_i \Phi \, d^3 r
$$
Expanding $\partial_i \Phi$ in a Taylor series about the origin, we have
\begin{align}
F_i &= 
-\iiint \rho \left[ \left. \partial_i \Phi \right|_\mathbf{0} + \left. r_j \partial_i \partial_j \Phi \right|_\mathbf{0} + \left. \frac{1}{2} r_j r_k \partial_i \partial_j \partial_k \Phi \right|_\mathbf{0} \right]  \, d^3 r \\
&= - \left. \partial_i \Phi \right|_\mathbf{0} \left[ \iiint \rho  \, d^3 r \right] - \left. \partial_i \partial_j \Phi \right|_\mathbf{0} \left[ \iiint r_j \rho  \, d^3 r \right] - \frac{1}{2} \left. \partial_i \partial_j \partial_k \Phi \right|_\mathbf{0} \left[ \iiint r_j r_k \rho  \, d^3 r \right] - \cdots\\
\end{align}
The first integral can be seen to simply be the mass $M$ of the object.  The second integral is proportional to the dipole moment of the object, which vanishes because we have chosen our origin to be at the center of mass.  Finally, the third term can be rewritten in terms of the quadrupole moment of the object:
\begin{align}
\left. \partial_i \partial_j \partial_k \Phi \right|_\mathbf{0} &\left[ \iiint r_j r_k \rho  \, d^3 r \right] \\ &= \left. \partial_i \partial_j \partial_k \Phi \right|_\mathbf{0} \left[ \iiint \left(r_j r_k \rho - \frac{1}{3} r^2 \delta_{jk} \right)  \, d^3 r \right] + \frac{1}{3} \left. \partial_i \partial_j \partial_k \Phi \right|_\mathbf{0} \delta_{jk} \left[ \iiint r^2 \rho \, d^3 r \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{3} \left. \partial_i \partial_j \partial_k \Phi \right|_\mathbf{0} Q_{jk} + \frac{1}{3} \left. \partial_i \nabla^2 \Phi \right|_\mathbf{0} \left[ \iiint r^2 \rho \, d^3 r \right]
\end{align}
and the last term vanishes because $\nabla^2\Phi = 0$ at all points.

So putting this all together, we have
$$
F_i = - M \left. \partial_i \Phi \right|_\mathbf{0} - \frac{1}{6} \left. \partial_i \partial_j \partial_k \Phi \right|_\mathbf{0} Q_{jk} - \cdots
$$
where the ellipsis stands for higher-order couplings to even higher multipole moments.

In your case, then, the fact that star $A$ has a quadrupole moment means that the force on it is not equal to $-M_A \nabla \Phi_A$;  there will be an additional term that depends on the quadrupole moment of $A$.  Meanwhile, star $B$ doesn't have its own quadrupole moment; but the potential $\Phi_B$ that is seen by star $B$ has a term proportional to the quadrupole moment of $A$.  For both objects, the force experienced depends on the quadrupole moment of $A$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I tried to apply your equations but the two forces are different for a factor 9/2. I updated my question above. Do you see any mistakes?

Comment: "Only if an object is spherically symmetric will the gravitational force on it be equal to the force on a point mass at the same position as the object's CM." I didn't follow your math, but this statement appears to contradict the result that the motion of a system of particles can be calculated as if the net external force were acting on a single particle located at the c.m.

Comment: @Not_Einstein:  The net external force on the extended object can be calculated by summing up all the forces on the individual particles.  However, it's not always the case that the center of gravity is the same as the center of mass, and so you can't always treat the gravitational force as though it acts at the center of mass.  [See this Q&A](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/50107/what-is-the-difference-between-center-of-mass-and-center-of-gravity) and [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centers_of_gravity_in_non-uniform_fields).

Comment: @gravitone123: Concerning the detailed calculation you've done, I can think of a couple of possible resolutions:  (a) there are different conventions for the quadrupole moment;  I was using $Q_{ij} = \iiint (3 r_i r_j - \delta_{ij} r^2) \rho$.  You should confirm that the source you're using for your gravitational field expression uses the same convention. ...

Comment: ...  (b)  I don't think that it's true that the only important component of $Q$ is $Q_{rr}$. In particular, $\partial_r \partial_{\theta} \partial_{\theta} \Phi$ and $\partial_r \partial_{\phi} \partial_{\phi} \Phi$ are non-zero as well, so you have to include the contributions from those components of $Q$.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert $\Phi_A$ depends only on $r$. So angular derivatives $\partial_{\theta,\phi}$ should be zero..

Comment: @gravitone123:  Fair point, that was badly stated.  Rephrasing:  my expression $\partial_i \partial_j \partial_k \Phi$ assumed Cartesian components.  In spherical coordinates this derivative operator would look different, similar to how expressions for Laplacians & divergences take different forms in spherical coordinates.  You could either try to derive these expressions in spherical coordinates (ugh), or you can just work in a local set of Cartesian coordinates with $\Phi = - G M_B/\sqrt{(x - r)^2 + y^2 + z^2}$ and take derivatives with respect to $x$, $y$, and $z$.  ...

Comment: ... The point remains that the $r \theta \theta$- and $r \phi \phi$-components of this derivative tensor will be non-zero and you have to take into account their interactions with the "transverse" components of $Q$.

Comment: @Michael Seifert  "...so you can't always treat the gravitational force as though it acts at the center of mass." I'm still confused. In the familiar derivation of the motion of a system of particles, there are no assumptions on the nature of the forces acting on each particle. Those are summed to get the net external force. That net force can be considered to act on a single particle at the c.m. of the system. How is this not completely general? What assumption is made in the derivation such that you can't treat the gravitational force as acting at the c.m.?

Comment: @Not_Einstein:  What's true is that the *acceleration* of the CM of a system is the same as that of a point mass with mass $M$ experiencing the total external force on the system, whatever that external force might be.  What's *not* always true is that the total external force on the system can be calculated as though there was a single point mass at the location of the CM.  ...

Comment: ... For a contrived example (but perhaps more illustrative), imagine that my system consists of me and Alpha Centauri, and I want to find the force on this system due to the gravity of the Earth. The CM of the system is pretty close to Alpha Centauri (I've gained some weight recently but not that much.) The force on the system from the Earth consists of about 800 N on me and about 3 N on Alpha Centauri. If we replaced that with a point particle at the CM with the same total mass, the resulting force would still be pretty close to 3 N — not the same as the total force on the system ...

Comment: ... But if I jumped off a cliff, the acceleration of the CM of the system would be the same as if there was an 803–N force on a point particle whose mass is that of me plus that of Alpha Centauri.

Answer (score 0):

When you consider an interaction between two things, the potential energy due to interaction is a shared entity between both of them.

Consider a mass connected to another mass via a spring. In the usual form, you have a mass connected via a spring to a wall, and you get the $\dfrac12kx^2$, but when you have two movable masses connected by the same spring, it will be $\dfrac12k(x_B-x_A)^2$, i.e. one spring EPE term shared between both of them, not two separate terms.

Same thing here, you write down the GPE for both particles at once, and so it is
$$\text{GPE}=-\frac{GMm}r-\frac{3GMQ}{2r^3}$$

In practice, you just work using reduced mass and things will be less confusing.

Comment: So it is better to first write the potential energy of the system and then deriving to find the force.  And the force obtained in this way is for both the stars. It is right?

Comment: Yes, it will be for both stars. But you might want to just use the reduced mass scheme and then you will only have to worry about the one-body problem. The resulting simplicity is so great, that it is definitely worth the effort learning it. Then you transform back to the usual coördinates, and see that both stars are moving.

Comment: Ok. Your answer, however, prompted me to have a related question: What does it represent the derivative (say w.r.t. x) of a multi-particle system energy potential ? In the case of 2 particles, it is simply the gravity force, but for 3 or more particles ?

Comment: Why would it be anything else? Each type of interaction that gives rise to a potential, will generate the correct interaction forces upon differentiation. Elastic potential energy gives Hooke's law. Gravitational potential gives weight.