# Is it valid to expand a line of charge into a sphere?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, gauss-law

Basically, the situation is:

```
  y  
  ^    
  |  
  |  
  |  
  |  
<=|====================----------p-----------------> x
```

... where the ='s represent a line of uniform charge (with given charge q) and given length L. The goal is to find the electric field generated by that charge at point p, a given distance from the end of the line of charge.

My intuition says that the way to solve the problem is to expand the line into a sphere of charge surrounding the bar with radius 1/2L.  At that point, since I can treat a uniformly charged sphere as a point charge, and the sphere would be uniformly charged *in the x direction only* (or maybe better to say that it produces a perfectly symmetrical field pointed in the +/-x direction), I can treat the line of charge as a point charge centered at 1/2L.

Is this a valid approach to solving this problem, and if not, why not?

---

<sub>**Disclaimer:** This is a homework question, so I'm trying to follow normal SE homework policy.  Please let me know if I'm letting you down.  :)</sub>

Comment: A good idea,  but how would you know it's a correct idea?   The only way to know is to solve the problem without using any approximations or guesses, such as a careful application of Coulomb's law.  (You are *guessing* that your procedure is correct.)

Comment: Just a question: I do not understand when you write "and the sphere would be uniformly charged _in the x direction only_"... how is the distribution of the charge in the sphere?

Comment: The charge would be spread far thinner in a cross-section of the sphere in the yz plane say at point L than at a point very close to the origin.  This means that if you took a point above the x-axis, a symmetry argument would be utterly impossible, whereas along the x-axis all charges in the yz plane of reference would have a balancing charge exactly across the x-axis, producing only charge in the +x direction.

Comment: Again, let me know if I'm being totally illogical; I'm not actually a Phys student; I'm a bio student doing a Physics course for interest's sake and also because it's required for my degree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the sphere would be uniformly charged in the x direction only

You can treat a uniformly charged sphere as a point charge at its centre, but as you area aware the sphere you are creating would not be uniformly charged. The [Shell Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem) which allows you to replace a sphere with a point charge requires that the sphere must have a spherically symmetric charge density.

Even if you rearranged the line charge into a uniformly charged sphere this would not give the correct answer. It is rarely possible to transform one charge distribution into another without changing the electric field it produces, even for a single point such as P.

> I can treat the line of charge as a point charge centered at 1/2L

This is more sensible but still incorrect. The electric field of a charge distribution is not the same as that of a point of the same total charge at the geometric centre (centroid) of the distrubution.

We can often treat the inertial mass of an object as though it were concentrated at its centroil (the **centre of mass**), but this only works for gravitational mass if the gravitational field which it is place in is uniform. See [Will centre of gravity coincide with centre of mass if density of object is non-uniform?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/254960)

The same is true for electrical forces, which are also of the form $1/r^2$. The electric fields from 2 point charges at distances $\pm x$ from the centre of the line do not add up to twice that at the centre.

Comment: I was thinking about the possibility of mentioning the multipole expansion and put it into the context of the last part of the question. But it might be too off topic?

Comment: @secavara Sorry I don't feel capable of expressing an opinion about that, except to say that it would probably be beyond the OP's understanding. If you think it is relevant and answers the question go ahead and post an answer.