# Why is center of gravity a different quantity than center of mass?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I thought the center of mass equation was derived for general forces,
$$\sum{\vec{F_{ext}}}=M\vec{a_{CM}}$$

Then suddenly when the external force on the $i$ particle is of the form $m_ig_i$, where $g_i$ varies throughout the body, we have to use this equation:

$$\vec{W}=M\vec{a_{CG}}$$

where $CG$ is a different point than $CM$. So, what makes gravity special?

EDIT: I'm not asking the difference between them. They have different formulas, so obviously they have different values when $g$ is not constant.

I'm asking why doesn't the resultant gravitational force or $W$ can't be thought of as acting on the center of mass when the center of mass equation is derived for any general external force.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between centre of mass & centre of gravity for massive bodies?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/151402/)

Comment: @Mitchell I'm asking why the weight of a body can't be thought of as acting on the center of mass? I thought the center of mass equation is derived for general external forces. Which part of the derivation is not valid when the external force is gravity?

Comment: At least give that question a read.

Comment: @Mitchell I did. The accepted answer just gives two different formulas. Why does gravity pull an object at the point calculated by the second formula while of all other types of forces act on the point given by first formula?

Comment: `the center of mass equation is derived for any general external force`: Not true. The center of mass is simply a (mass) weighted average position, it makes no reference to any force, generic or not.

Comment: @stafusa The derivation of $\sum \vec{F_{ext}} = M \frac{d^2}{dt^2} \left(\frac{\sum m_i\vec{r_i}}{M}\right)$ doesn't assume anything about the nature of $\vec{F_{ext}}$.

Comment: But it's also *not* the definition of [center of mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass#Definition).

Comment: @stafusa The derivation of the result that the net force acting on a body is equal to mass times the acceleration of the center of mass doesn't assume anything about the nature of the net force.

Comment: Now I almost want this question weren't closed so that I could post a proper answer. The point is that your 1st eq. is still valid for the gravitational force, and what the 2nd eq. tells you is that $W$ doesn't have to act on the center of mass (CM), meaning, e.g., that *besides* accelerating the CM of the object, it might, when non-uniform, exert also a torque on it. [This answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/329054/75633) explains it in more detail.